# change emacs bash colors for ls command

Tags: bash, emacs, colors

I have enabled dircolors to change the ls command to have yellow for folders when using ls.  The problem is that when I use the shell in emacs, it still shows them as navy blue which is hard to read on a black background.

**How can I change the colors for the bash shell, or more particularly, the ls command.**  My color changes work on a opened terminal, but not for emacs.  I have emacs23 with X support.

Comment: I use `alias ls="ls -CF"` to not depend on colors.  `M-x eshell` works good with colors.

Comment: @vpit3833 - I've been using `emacs` for years but did not know of `eshell` .. thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using ansi-color, it take the colors from the ansi-color-names-vector, the default is:

```
  ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "blue" "magenta" "cyan" "white"]
```

You can customize the colors of the shell output altering the ansi-color-names-vector variable.

Here is mine, work well with zenburn theme.

```
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
      ["black" "tomato" "PaleGreen2" "gold1"
       "DeepSkyBlue1" "MediumOrchid1" "cyan" "white"])
```

To see the changes, evaluate the next expresion, and the next out take it in consideration

```
(setq ansi-color-map (ansi-color-make-color-map))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell` …

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `shell` <kbd>RET</kbd> says:

> If a file `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME' exists, or`~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh',
>   it is given as initial input (but this may be lost, due to a timing
>   error, if the shell discards input when it starts up).

So if you export your `LS_COLORS` environment variable in `~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh`, Emacs should use it.

Edit: hmmm... I'm no longer sure that `shell` supports this. (I'm having issues with Vista+Cygwin, at any rate!)

You may also like to try out <kbd>M-x</kbd> `term` or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ansi-term` ?

Comment: not sure what issues you're seeing but if you want color in emacs shells, you probably need to use:

(require 'ansi-color) and then M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on